# PERL Script : problems with mkdir and chdir

Tags: perl, perl-module, file-copying

```
checkAndCreateDirectory();
moveFiles();
sub checkAndCreateDirectory {
    my $dirname = "launchpad/config/com/adobe/granite/auth/saml/SamlAuthenticationHandler";
    my @folders = split /\/|\\/, $dirname;
    map { mkdir $_; chdir $_; } @folders;
}
sub moveFiles {
    my $source_dir = "SamlAuthenticationHandler";
    my $destination_dir = "launchpad/config/com/adobe/granite/auth/saml/SamlAuthenticationHandler";
    opendir(my $DIR, $destination_dir) || die "can't opendir $source_dir: $!";
    move("$source_dir", "$destination_dir") or die "FAIL : Unable to add config -> $!";
}
```

**checkAndCreateDirectory()** and **moveFiles()** subroutines are running fine with sepaerate script but when tried to run in same script it throws error : **No such file or directory**

Can anyone please help me in figuring out the issue? Is there any issue with

> map { mkdir $*; chdir $*; } @folders;

?

Comment: Try print the error message in `$!`: `mkdir $_ or die "Could not create folder '$_': $!"`

Comment: Se also `make_path` in [File::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path) it will create all the nonexistent directories in one call

Comment: Using `map` in a void context is a sign you probably should have been using `for` instead.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I tried printing the error msg but all I am getting is "No such file or directory at run.pl line 11". And thanks for your help, *make_path* is working fine and is creating nonexistent directories as well but I am just curious to find out the problem with above mentioned code.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you `chdir` into all of your subdirectories of `checkAndCreateDirectory` but never return to where you started, so when you call `moveFiles`, you are in the wrong place and cannot find your `$destination_dir`.

I would simplify your script like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Copy::Recursive qw( dirmove );
use File::Path qw( make_path );

my $saml_handler_path = 'launchpad/config/com/adobe/granite/auth/saml/SamlAuthenticationHandler';

make_path $saml_handler_path
    or die "Unable to create path '$saml_handler_path' : $!";

my $source_dir = "SamlAuthenticationHandler";
my $dest_dir = $saml_handler_path;

dirmove( $source_dir, $dest_dir )
    or die "Unable to move $source_dir to $dest_dir : $!";
```